# Как сохранять данные в текстовой файл без пробелов на C#?

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста ,как правильно писать данные (строки) в txt файл без пробелов, или как удалять пробелы на лету перед записью в файл?

К примеру такой код сохраняет линки/строки с пробелами:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(content , @"(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,php?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");
string result = "";
foreach (Match m in matches)
    result = result + m.Value + "\r\n";

lock (this.lockValid)
    this.valid++;

StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter("Out.txt" , true);
writer1.WriteLine(result);
writer1.Close();
```

Comment: А откуда берутся пробелы? Покажите пример оригинального текста, что получается, и что вам реально нужно.

Comment: И что-то я сомневаюсь, что часть паттерна `[\w\-\.,php?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]` правильная.

Comment: Патерн правильный по крайней мере в моем случай, вообщем условие: 'if (content.Contains("http://") || content.Contains("https://"))'

Comment: Да, и [\w\-\.,php?^=%&amp;:/~\+#], и [\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#] имеют не тот смысл, который автор в них вкладывал. Если только регулярки в c# работают по другим правилам.

Comment: @Visman: регулярки в C# отличаются от других только мелкими деталями.

Comment: Патерн правильный по крайней мере в моем случай, вообщем условие:                                                                                                                 if (content.Contains("http://") || content.Contains("https://")) если в контенте нет "http://" или "https://" то в файл сохраняются пустые строки(пробелы) как понял щас, не могу понять ток как сделать чтобы пустые условия игнорировались? не как не получается может как то есть возможность очищать от пробелов пропустив через масив данные?

Comment: Вы бы пример в вопрос дописали. Какие у вас входные данные и что должно получиться. А то так довольно трудно понять ваш вопрос.

Comment: Да, и полный оффтоп: И почему на этом ресурсе полно женских ников, а в тексте авторы пишут в мужском лице? :) P.S. Может это ИИ тренируется на нас с вами?

Comment: @Visman: Предполагаю, что `Sveta` — не имя, а родительный падеж от «svet». Плюс CamelCase всего ника.

Comment: На счет ника прочитайте внимательнее, "ГЕНЕРАТОРСВЕТА" это не значит что имя Cвета))) Вообщем по теме надо парсить линки с нескольких сайтов, вид линков не важен все правильно парсится не в этом суть, например открываем первый сайт парсим все линки подходящие под патерн при условии что в контенте присутсвует нужное значение и сахроняем в файл, и так же делее второе третье.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня сохраняется в файле линки так:                                                                                    линк1                                                                                                            линк2                                                                                               пробел / пустая строка                                                                                                            ну и Т.Д. каждый линк с новой строки сохраняется..

Comment: Надо чтобы сохранялись так же но без пустых строк...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей задаче лучше использовать `StringBuilder`. Попробуйте так:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(content , @"(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,php?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match m in matches)
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value))
        sb.AppendLine(m.Value.Trim());

File.AppendAllText("Out.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: И ещё сделать: `m.Value.Trim()`

Comment: Во другое дело, все отлично работает спасибо большое.